# Regarding SPLongOperation Object In SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api, object-model

I am using the SPLongOperation Object in my project to introduce a delay while navigating to a new page.The in-built page uses the default css styles and branding.

I want to customize this page design and apply my own theme and branding.

Please tell me how to apply a custom master page to the page which displays the SharePoint 2007 Spin Wheel having the animated gears_an.gif image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to 2007, but here is another option that allows more control: http://ruudheemskerk.net/archive/2009/11/24/long-operations-in-sharepoint-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Alex is right that the only (unsupported!) way to change the page layout would be to update gear.aspx on the file system of each WFE. Note that this would be a farm-wide change unless you're using a copy of LAYOUTS, which is generally recommended if you decide to go this route.

If you really want to get clever, the values of the operation's `LeadingHTML` and `TrailingHtml` properties aren't escaped before they are written to the response stream. You could use one of those properties to write a `<script>` to manipulate the DOM, inject a stylesheet link, etc.

**Update:** I put together a quick proof-of-concept of script injection [here](http://solutionizing.net/2009/07/03/stylish-gears-customizing-splongoperation/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree that the only was is to modify the OOB files.

You can solve this without bending the rules by developing a custom HTTPModule. This HTTPModule will detect if you are accessing the page in question and modify its master page according to the following snippet:

```
private void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Page page = sender as Page;
  // Do your checking/filtering here
  if (true)
  {
    page.MasterPageFile = "<whatever you have.master";
  }
}
```

Comment: Except that SPLongOperation just writes directly to the response stream without processing the host page's master/control hierarchy at all. An HttpModule is usually an option, but I don't think it helps here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [SPLongOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splongoperation.aspx) class is sealed and also hard-codes the gears ASPX file.

It looks like the only way you can changes this is by editing the `12\template\layouts\gear.aspx` file. Note that this may cause problems with future product updates that make changes to this file.